# How to multiply with d/dx operator?

Tags: operator-theory

$Q_{l}^{\dagger} Q_{l} =\left(+\frac{d}{d x}+\frac{l+1}{x}-\frac{1}{l+1}\right)\left(-\frac{d}{d x}+\frac{l+1}{x}-\frac{1}{l+1}\right) \\
=-\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}-\frac{l+1}{x^{2}}+\frac{l+1}{x} \frac{d}{d x}-\frac{l+1}{x} \frac{d}{d x}+\frac{(l+1)^{2}}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{l+1} \frac{d}{d x}-\frac{1}{l+1} \frac{d}{d x}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{(l+1)^2} \\
=-\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}+\frac{l(l+1)}{x^{2}}-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{(l+1)^{2}} \\
$

So I understand the first row but where do the third and eighth terms come from in the second row?
I would expect that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{-1}{l+1} = 0$ but apparently that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two operators $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $h(x)$: operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ maps function $f(x)$ to $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ and $h(x)$ maps $f(x)$ to $f(x) h(x)$.
What is the product of operators $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $h(x)$? To answer this question, let us apply them to a function $f(x)$:

$$\left(\frac{d}{dx} \circ h(x)\right) f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (h(x) f(x)) = \frac{dh(x)}{dx} f(x) + h(x) \frac{df(x)}{dx} = \left(\frac{dh(x)}{dx} + h(x) \frac{d}{dx}\right) f(x),$$

We conclude that the product of operators $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $h(x)$ equals $\frac{dh(x)}{dx} + h(x) \frac{d}{dx}$ (and not $\frac{dh(x)}{dx}$).